# Inconsistent results with snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels_min and snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels_max

Tags: alsa

I am trying to get the minimum and maximum number of channels supported by my device. The results are unexpected and random. They change at each execution. Did I miss something?

```c
// file : capture_nb_chan.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int err;
  snd_pcm_t             *capture_handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t   *hw_params;
  unsigned int min, max;

  // Open audio device
  if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&capture_handle, "hw:0,0", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0)
    exit (1);

  // Allocate hardware parameters
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc (&hw_params)) < 0)
    exit (1);

  // Initialize parameters
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any (capture_handle, hw_params)) < 0)
    exit (1);

  // Get min and max number of channels
  err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels_min(hw_params, &min);
  if (err < 0)
    exit (1);
  fprintf(stdout, "Min channels: %u. (%d)\n", min, err);
  err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels_max(hw_params, &max);
  if (err < 0)
    exit (1);
  fprintf(stdout, "Max channels: %u. (%d)\n", max, err);
}
```

Compile the script with

```
gcc -o capture_nb_chan capture_nb_chan.c -lasound
```

Execute it with

```
./capture_nb_chan
```

Output is

```
Min channels: 22031. (2)
Max channels: 681205789. (2)
```

Output values are random while error code is **`2`** when it's expected to be `0` or negative according to [documentation](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___h_w___params.html#gac6c37a5da7dc8cb19fdd8e9cf1bd673d).

Comment: I wonder if this would be more appropriate on Stack Overflow, since it seems wrapped tightly with coding against the ALSA API?

Comment: Works for me. Did you try on another machine?

Comment: Both ways work, Bebs V. The benefit to having you re-post it is that it ensures you have an SO account, and that it gets proper tags. I'm happy to do it, otherwise. Let me know.

Comment: @CL, thanks for your feedback. I have no means to try on another machine right now, but I'll try soon. Can you tell me your alsa version?

Comment: @JeffSchallerI copied it on SO, and wrote an answer. Should I also copy the answer here in case it helps someone? It wasn't a problem of coding, bur rather a problem of version.